# the best "place" to invoke business logic in a Tapestry page?

Tags: java, validation, web-applications, tapestry, business-logic

[Tapestry version: 5.4-rc-1]

What is the best "place" to put/invoke business logic in a Tapestry page? I can see a lot of examples using for that the `onValidate()` method (the validate event fired by the form at the end of the validation).
At the moment I do this:

- Inside the form submission event handler: I just store in a variable the "form context" (something like: 'addThis', 'removeThat', 'partialUpdate', 'save'). This is because I could trigger the form submit from different submit/linksubmit components - potentially executing different business logic
- Inside `onValidate()` method: I validate the received data and use the "form context" to execute/invoke different business logic
- Inside `onSuccess()` or `onFailure()`: I just think about rendering zones/loading some javascript functions/preparing messages to visualise

I don't like too much "mixing" business logic with validation and I was wondering if someone would suggest a different/better approach - the only alternative that I see is to move everything inside `onSuccess()` and handle an eventual exception there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to identify what "Business logic" you are referring to. Are you using your services to validate something, the obvious place is `onValidate()`. An example of validation Business Logic we use is ensuring the domain of an email actually exists by doing a DNS MX record check. Or checking if a username already exists or not.

We always place any [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) service calls in the `onSuccess()` method followed by preparing the resulting view and returning it.

We only use `onFailure()` to prepare the view in case the `onValidate()` (Either at a form level or an individual field level) threw a [ValidationException](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ValidationException.html) of some sort. In our case `onFailure()` never invokes any Business Logic.

If you indeed have multiple submit buttons, using a local variable to store which one was invoked so your subsequent `onValidate()`, `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` know what is requested of them is a trick we too use.

In your question there is one method missing we often use which is [`onPrepare(Context formContext)`](http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html#FormsandValidation-FormEvents) to setup the form handeling using the passed in context. Very usefull to ensure you're not sticking variables in your `HttpSession` and/or when using the form inside a loop.